# How do I know whether the value is inserted automatically or needs to be inserted manually?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

well I'm using MS SQL Server (mostly working with the Management Studio) and I can't find out how to know what values from a table do I have to insert and what values are created automatically? How do I view that?
I mean ID's are often calculated automatically, but sometimes you need to insert them by hand, so how exactly can I find out/see that?

Comment: check `identity specification` property, it will tell you if `identity increment` is true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), run the following in a query window/tab:

```
USE [DBNameWhereTableResides]
EXEC sp_help 'SchemaName.TableName'
```

OR

```
EXEC DBNameWhereTableResides.dbo.sp_help 'SchemaName.TableName'
```

You will see entries for "Identity" and "RowGuidCol" that will tell you if the ID is auto-generated.

You will also see a section for Constraints, first column shown being "constraint_type", that will show any DEFAULT constraints that will pre-fill a colummn if the value is not specified in the INSERT.

The second section shows all of the column definitions and the ones marked as "Nullable" = "yes" don't need to be in the INSERT but without being an IDENTITY field or having a DEFAULT it won't get a value and will remain NULL if not specified in the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to find all tables and id columns

```
SELECT  s.name + '.' + t.name AS TableName,  c.name AS ColumnName,  
 IDENT_SEED(s.name + '.' + t.name) AS Seed, 
 IDENT_INCR(s.name + '.' + t.name) AS Increment
 FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    AND c.is_identity = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
( 
    id int IDENTITY, 'this will be automatically inserted
    product_name VARCHAR(30),
    description varchar(200),
    price money NOT NULL
)

INSERT Product (product_name) VALUES ('Strawberry', 1200);
```

Note: I did not specify "id" in my insert.
You don't have to specify "description", the default will be null
Any column mark NOT NULL must be specified e.g. PRICE